# upgrading rails app from 5.0.0.rc2 to 5.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie so please bear with me :)

I am currently working on my personal project running on rails 5.0.0.rc2. How can I best upgrade my project to use the latest version 5.0.0?

I did some research and found that I could just easily change the rails gem in Gemfile and run 'bundle update rails'. I don't know if this is the best way, but if it's not, what's the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing this the correct way but be sure to run bundle update to catch any dependency changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Gemfile, check `gem 'rails'` and set it's version like this

```
gem 'rails', '5.0.0'
```

the use bundle to install it by running

```
bundle install
```

or

```
bundle
```

you may encounter some dependencies that require you to run

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the rails version in the Gemfile would be enough. Also be sure to check out [railsdiff.org](http://railsdiff.org) for changes in the project directory (config files, etc.)